# "Ask Question" Formatting Problem

Tags: bug, user-interface, design

Is it just me, or is the format of the "Ask Question" page kind of broken. Here's a screenshot from a recent question of mine:

[image: askMissFormat]

I faced two problems:

1. "How to Tag" mixes up with the footer and
2. the tag I was looking for [arithmetic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic-functions) hides behind the footer

I realized, that, when I edit the question, at least all the tags showed appropriately, which might be, because the footer is further down now.

[image]

Comment: I have at least witnessed the "How to Tag" bit messing up with the footer. Chrome latest, Win 7, should it matter.

Comment: I can confirm this occurs for me as well. A similar problem also exists with some of the moderator tools. Chrome latest, Fedora 17.

Comment: Also confirm, at least with the tag drop-down being hidden behind the footer (my screen is a bit on the big side...). Debian Linux, Firefox/IceWeasel 21.

Comment: I can confirm both on my 64bit Arch Linux/Firefox 21; and on my 32bit Windows 8/Firefox 21.

Answer (score 1):

Although I hate TouchPads, they force me to ways not to use them. By that I found that it's at least possible to navigate through the tags via your cursor buttons, which finally makes all of them visible.